# could not successfully use "pip install" package for Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, zsh, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

#### Problem

In terminal, after running `pip install` to install packages successfully, I get `ImportError: No module named XX` information in Jupyter notebook, but could successfully import it in terminal.

For example, I installed a package "xx",
running `pip list` in Jupyter notebook and terminal, but only finding "xx" in terminal result.

But when I run `Users/name/anaconda2/bin/pip install xx`, I could successfully import xx in Jupyter notebook but could not import it in terminal.

I want to know the reasons and hope that every time when running `pip install`, packages should be installed in Anaconda.

#### Environment

Mac OSX (El Capitan Version 10.11.5)

In terminal,

- run `python` , result is:

`Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin`

- run `which python`,result is:

`/Users/name/anaconda2/bin/python`

- run `which pip`,result is:

`/usr/local/bin/pip`

- run `less .zshrc`(my default shell is Zsh), part of result are:

  ```
  # User configuration
  export PATH="/Users/name/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
  export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  # export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
  ```

For Anaconda and Jupyter notebook, I installed them by downloading "PYTHON 2.7-Mac OSX 64"(GRAPHICAL INSTALLER and Command Line Installer) from [the official website](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

note: I use  "name" to replace my real account username

I know I could use `alias` to get the results but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Why are you using pip to manage Anaconda packages?

Comment: some packages could not installed from ``conda install``

Comment: Anyways, it would appear your Jupyter kernel is not pointing to the correct installation of Python

Comment: Also, if you are inside of a conda environment, `pip` will install packages into that environment.